# execa is not a function react electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am trying to convert a project of mine into a react electron app using the most up to date node / npm / electron / react versions, and making sure there are no vulnerabilities with `npm audit`

I use `execa` to run ffmpeg commands, using the code inside the dev branch of my repo:
https://github.com/MartinBarker/rendertune-react-dev/blob/dev/src/Components/FFmpeg.js#L17

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

/////////////////  execa created here
const execa = window.require('execa');

const readline = window.require('readline');
const moment = window.require("moment");
const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron');

async function newstartRender(renderSettings={}){
    console.log('Ffmpeg.js newstartRender() ',renderSettings)
    let {cmdArgs,outputDuration} = createFfmpegCommand(renderSettings.audioFiles, renderSettings.imageFiles, renderSettings.outputFilepath, renderSettings.outputWidth, renderSettings.outputHeight)
    const ffmpegPath = getFfmpegPath('ffmpeg');
    console.log('outputDuration=',outputDuration)
    console.log('cmdArgs=',cmdArgs.join(' '),'\n calling execa \n')
    
//////////////// execa called here
    const process = execa(ffmpegPath, cmdArgs);
```

But when the line `const process = execa(ffmpegPath, cmdArgs);` gets called, it gives me an error:

```
FFmpeg.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: execa is not a function
    at newstartRender (FFmpeg.js:17:1)
    at startRender (Project.js:99:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
```

I am confused because In a previous project, using the same exact code, it works fine:
https://github.com/MartinBarker/RenderTune/blob/dev/src/FFmpeg.js#L17

```
import React from 'react';
import { isPackaged } from 'electron-is-packaged';

///////// working execa
const execa = window.require('execa');
const readline = window.require('readline');
const moment = window.require("moment");
const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron');

function newstartRender(renderSettings={}){
    console.log('Ffmpeg.js newstartRender() ',renderSettings)
    let {cmdArgs,outputDuration} = createFfmpegCommand(renderSettings.audioFiles, renderSettings.imageFiles, renderSettings.outputFilepath, renderSettings.outputWidth, renderSettings.outputHeight)
    const ffmpegPath = getFfmpegPath('ffmpeg');
    console.log('outputDuration=',outputDuration)
    console.log('cmdArgs=',cmdArgs.join(' '),'\n calling execa \n')

//////// working execa
    const process = execa(ffmpegPath, cmdArgs);
```

How can I fix my new repo / project, to prevent this `TypeError: execa is not a function` message?

Comment: is your webPreferences "nodeIntegration": true in browser window config?

Comment: yes, in both projects nodeIntegration is set to true